# Copy the value of all nodes matching an XPath using the browser console?

Tags: xpath, copy-paste

On a webpage that lists items there are two values for each item. I would like to copy these values into a spreadsheet. I have created two XPaths

```
//*[@id="promotion-articles"]/div[1]/ul/li/div[2]/div[1]/a/span

//*[@id="promotion-articles"]/div[1]/ul/li/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]
```

that matches the two values (and returns hundreds of nodes). Is there an easy way to copy these values so I can use them in an external tool?

Comment: Huh?  Not sure I understand.  Copy what value?  The xpath strings, or the results.  Please clarify in question.  Thanks

Comment: check if GoogleSheet with [ImportXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) satisfies your requirement. You just have to pass the url and the xpath, the data will be populated in the google sheet.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Each line on this webpage looks something like `item val1 val2`. The xpath points to val1 or val2.

Comment: @supputuri It looked extremely promising but when I tried "Error
Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.". Any idea how to split things up?